# checking browser history from cmd or java

Tags: java, browser, browser-history

Is there any way I can check my browser history via java program or command line?
My requirement is I need to check how many times a person has accessed a particular site in a day from the browser.

Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Comment: Is this a site you host ? or do you just want to snoop users on a network ? .. There are a couple apps which do this

Comment: Hi ,I have to know that the particular site is visited when, lets take google.com or any other in past 1 day, can you pls provide me the names of app by which we can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can view cached DNS entries from CMD.

Every time you browse to a web page, your PC has to request the IP Address for that web site from your default DNS server, and then caches them locally on your machine for a while to speed up future access to that web site — even in a private browsing session.

You can see these for yourself by opening up a command prompt and typing in **ipconfig /displaydns** to see the full list of cached DNS entries.

Now, the first thing you’ll notice is that a whole lot of information will appear, to the point that all of it can’t fit in the command prompt. What you can do is take the output of the command and send it to a text file somewhere on your machine.

```
ipconfig /displaydns > c:\desired location
```

Now, when you open that file you’ll see information about the websites you've visited directly or indirectly.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response, but my main aim is to get particular visited site such as gmail.com in the last one day only?                     As I see ipconfig/displaydns does not show the time when the site was accessed. is there any way to do it?